# FluentNHibernate - Convention for setting Cache().ReadWrite() for HasMany-Relations

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, conventions

I am searching a way to set `.Cache().ReadWrite()` for `HasMany()`-Relations in a convention. I don't use Automapping. Has someone an idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using FNH 1.3 this is possible

```
public class CacheConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}
```

i do not know when in which Version it was introduced